# How to create a new line on CLI ?

Tags: php, command-line-interface

I want to display my response in the new line, but I couldn't figure it out on how to do that.

I run this command :

`C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\php.exe -f "C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\php\index.p
hp"`

Then I got this : `Start ........... End<br>bs-0003R`

**bs-0003R** is my response back.

Here is how I generate that line : `echo "<br>".strip_tags($response);`

Image:

[image]

I tried `\n` , `\\n` , `<br>` . Am I trying to do something that is impossible ?

Answer (score 1):

Opp, I got it, just add `. PHP_EOL` before returning my response.

I got this now :

[image]

Comment: You were too quick in response. Almost duplicated the answer.